# concat and minify js libs with webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have react app that uses webpack for bundling into single js file, webpack config looks like this: http://pastebin.com/qrTh92Lf

There are several 3rd party js libraries (e.g. jQuery, Bootstrap) that i want to concat and minify into another bundle to include into my index.html

I tried creating another entry in webpack with array of those libraries and outputted them successfully into bundle. 
But when i include that bundle into my index.html it acts like those libraries don't exist.

Comment: You need to declare any exposed globals in your Webpack. When they are loaded in your page any require calls will resolve them to the global variable such as React, $ etc.

Comment: Ok, and how exactly do i expose them in webpack?

Comment: See https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html#applications-and-externals

Comment: Actually, I think what you are trying to achieve is split vendor and app bundles. Have a look at this: https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html#split-app-and-vendor-code

Comment: Ok i did expose them like that, you can check my pastebin.
As for splitting, i need to create new js file and require all my libraries in it, and then create commonChunk and include that bundle instead of script tags?

Comment: If you create a separate vendor bundle then you don't need externals. You just make sure both bundles are loaded. Externals are for loading libraries on their own such as CDN. Sorry for the confusion I didn't realise what you were trying to do initially.